# Pyramid of letters based on input C#

Tags: c#

i have a certain exercise in C# that i'm having trouble with.

i need to print a pyramid of letters, based on the input of the user, every letter should be printed the number of times of its alphabet order. the head of the pyramid will always be 'a' and every row the letter will jump by 2.

example:

input: `g`

output: `a
       ccc
      eeeee
     ggggggg`

my try went wrong because i don't know how many spaces i need for the first row 'a' before and after the letter for the pyramid to stay a perfect pyramid.

```
numSpaces = 4 //just for test
    for (i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
    {
        printf(" ");
        numSpaces--;
    }
```

i guess this is somehow how the loop of the spaces should look like,

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: printf? Are you sure this is c#?

Comment: Hint: start backwards.

Comment: " i don't know how many spaces i need for the first row 'a' before and after the letter for the pyramid to stay a perfect pyramid."

Comment: You should start by getting the number of the input letter, so that you know how many spaces you need for 'a'

Comment: @Gilad, you will need 12 spaces for a, 11 for c, .... 0 for y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code snippet will help you to print a perfect pyramid. The important logic is printing spaces.

```
int i=0,j=0; char ch='g';
for(i='a';i<=ch;i=i+2){
    for(j=(ch-i)/2;j>0;j--){
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j='a';j<i+1;j++){
        printf("%c", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly! i need time to learn the logic of the space printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can start for loop with character `a` and use its ASCII code as start of counter. the counter increments by 2 in every iterate based on your logic. loop until `i` is less than or equal to ASCII code of input character.

You have to print `(letter - counter)/2` spaces and then print `i - 'a' + 1` letter.

```
char letter = 'g';

for (int i = 'a'; i <= letter; i += 2)
{
    Console.Write(new string(' ', (letter - i)/2));
    Console.WriteLine(new string((char) i, i - 'a' + 1));
}
```

Notes: because `i` is started from `a` then `i - 'a' + 1` will give the position in alphabet order

`letter - i` will give the inverse position(based on maximum `i` in loop which is `letter`). so when `i - 'a' + 1 == 1` then `letter - i == 6`. and also you have to divide this by 2 to make it pyramid shaped.